# Sqlite giving column more size than needed

Tags: database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have some data which I will be putting in the database. Say I make a field like "coupondetail text(10000)"  which will store the coupon detail, now consider that not all coupondetail will be 10,000 chars long. I m curious to know how much space will the column take in the database when the coupondetail text is lesser than 10,000 say 1000 chars?

Answer (score 3):

sqlite does not care much how you declare your column types and ignores any maximum length specified. [The declared type is just a hint](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity); any non-`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column can contain any type.

The size taken up in the database file depends on the values you put in. In the [record format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#record_format), strings are stored as length followed by string data. No empty space is necessarily left there.